# Word that best describes a set of people have gotten used to accepting mediocrity or failure

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

What is the word to describe when a person or set of people have gotten used to accepting mediocrity or failure

Comment: Do you mean a) for you to accept your own mediocrity or b) for you to accept the mediocrity of others?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What does your research show? What words have you tried and why did you reject them?

Comment: Can you provide us with an example of how you intend to use it?  Are you looking for an adjective to describe their attitude or a word for the people themselves?

Comment: *Unimaginative*, *uninspired*, *passionless*, *tired*, *useless*, *unproductive*, *uncreative*, *depressed*, *stuck in a rut*, *sad*, *cogs*, *drones*, *losers*. I will stop there. I deliberately didn't repeat any of the words from the existing answers. You need to provide much more guidance that you have. Who is this describing—yourself or somebody else? Are you looking for an adjective or a noun? What's the *nature* of this word? Please provide an example sentence with a blank into which the word would go.

Answer (score 2):

I think [resigned](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/resigned) would fit here:

> **resigned**: Willing to accept something unpleasant. *They are resigned and a little depressed at the thought of losing money for at least the first year.*

Answer (score 1):

Several words come close:

> [Apathetic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apathetic) - having or showing little or no feeling or emotion : SPIRITLESS
>
> [Perfunctory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perfunctory) - characterized by routine or superficiality, lacking in interest or enthusiasm
>
> [Stoic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic) -  not affected by or showing passion or feeling
>
> [Subdued](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subdued) - lacking in vitality or strength

Many of these can be used to display lack of desire to change, so context can show they're accepting of failure.

Answer (score 0):

inured, according to Merriam-Webster: accustomed to accepting something undesirable

Comment: Yes “ Inured” is the word.